# Is it possible to get stats on specific app versions installed from Android Market?

Tags: android, analytics

I recently released an updated version of my app on the Market and would like to know how many users have updated to the latest version.

I've looked in the Market help docs and on the Google Market dev forums with no luck.

Is there a way to get this metric from directly from Android Market? or do I need to add some 3rd party analytics to my app in order to track this. I'd like to avoid that if possible, as currently my app requires no permissions and I get feedback from my users that they like this and use my app over similiar apps because of this.

But if I do need to go down the road of using a third party analytics service, is using Google's own [SDK](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/) the simplest solution out there to collect this stats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am understanding your question,

Android market doesn't provide like this (get stats on specific app versions installed from Android Market), Try some third party analytics (I am using **FlurryAgent.jar** but what you needed I never tried). Try it.

**Analyze your android application**

Nice way to analyze your android application behavior: http://www.flurry.com/

**Flurry** is just small package that catches events inside your application and sends it to flurry server from time to time. You can see what functions are most useful in your application and even analyze exceptions remotely via web interface.

(This is my personal opinion for this question, if any other solution or third party library available then I don't know)